# Short selling in Islamic finance

Tags: sharia, finance

Does sharia finance allow you borrow an asset and re-sell it and then purchase it back at a later date in order to return the asset?

Assume that no finance charges (interest) is charged on the borrowed asset and the borrower posts 100% equivalent value of the borrowed asset as collateral to eliminate the risk of the borrower failing to return the borrowed asset.